# NodeJS remove outer json key, keep inner?

Tags: json, node.js

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "json": {
        "'1'-'V17511500523287'": [{
            "hits": 1,
            "sid": 1,
        }]
    }
}
```

I would like to turn it into:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "json": [{
        "hits": 1,
        "sid": 1,
    }],
    "length": 1
}
```

Meaning id like to remove `"'1'-'V17511500523287'"` but keep the inner content.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: What is `"'1'-'V17511500523287'"`? Can't you just do `outer.json = outer.json["'1'-'V17511500523287'"]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys(...) to get the keys in your result and then use it to get the inner content like you want.

Here is some code to achieve that. Put it in a function if you plan to do that elsewhere.

```
var response = {
    "result": "success",
    "json": {
        "'1'-'V17511500523287'": [{
            "hits": 1,
            "sid": 1,
       }]
    }
};

var response_keys = Object.keys(response.json);
response.length = response_keys.length;    

if (response_keys.length == 1) {
    response.json = response.json[response_keys[0]];
} else {
    // you can drop that if you don't want to handle more than one key,
    // or throw/return an error instead

    var _tmp = [];
    response_keys.forEach(function(key) {
        _tmp.push(response.json[key]);
    });
    response.json = _tmp;
    _tmp = undefined;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "json": [
    {
      "hits": 1,
      "sid": 1
    }
  ],
  "length": 1
}
```